# Best way to merge solution files

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio-2012, solution

I work on a project where there are atleast 200 projects on a single solution and every time I try to get latest code, there are 4 more projects added in the solution. Now this causes a lot of confusion. I have tried merging the solution by myself but whenever I tried that in the past, I end up messing something up. Probably I am not doing it right. I have a very specific question about solution. I have observed that solution is divided into 2 parts

```
 Project("{FAE04EC0-301F-11D3-BF4B-00C04F79EFBC}") = "Qualcomm.CPT.PostProcessing.Engine.States.Tests", "Qualcomm.CPT.PostProcessing.Engine.States.Tests\Qualcomm.CPT.PostProcessing.Engine.States.Tests.csproj", "{FA1C848D-2C23-45CF-80D9-21470857C539}"
EndProject
Project("{FAE04EC0-301F-11D3-BF4B-00C04F79EFBC}") = "Qualcomm.CPT.PostProcessing.Engine.States", "Qualcomm.CPT.PostProcessing.Engine.States\Qualcomm.CPT.PostProcessing.Engine.States.csproj", "{1C82AA5C-5819-46CB-8FD9-254E26E7FEAE}"
EndProject
```

Which I think refeers to each project in the solution and some respective IDs?

Now is the second pard which looks like following

```
        {388AAA9D-268E-407E-99DB-07A0F2ECD498}.Release|x64.ActiveCfg = Release|Any CPU
        {388AAA9D-268E-407E-99DB-07A0F2ECD498}.Release|x86.ActiveCfg = Release|Any CPU
        {388AAA9D-268E-407E-99DB-07A0F2ECD498}.WINDA|Any CPU.ActiveCfg = Debug|Any CPU
        {388AAA9D-268E-407E-99DB-07A0F2ECD498}.WINDA|Any CPU.Build.0 = Debug|Any CPU
```

My best guess is that the each line in second part corresponds to different configuraitons of each project in the first part and so on. However, my Perforce mergemanager, while merging  solution files gives me option of either selecting "servers's" code or MY code for some sections of this second part.

First of all this is really tough to read and very error prone. So to avoid the confusion, I just accept server's version and then add the projects manually. But that is cumbersome when I have a lot of projects to add.

is there any easy way out of this situation?

Comment: I don't like checking in solution files for this reason. Unless all active users working with the projects share common references within your source control or have same drive mappings it usually ends in chaos :(

Comment: I have similar issues when we checkin solutions files at the same time. It always causes a mess and only last week I lost an hour, repairing the solution file after the TFS Merge made a right mess of it. I currently however know of no nice way to merge solutions other than making sure only one programmer adds a project at a time, then the latest solution file is downloaded before another programmer adds another one. Easy in a small team not so much in a large one.